# Macro to automatically enter both SI and US length measurements

Tags: macros

How do I write a macro that, given the input `\length(100)` would interpret the input value as length (mm) and output something like `\SI{100}{\mm}/4''`, In other words, I need something that behind the scenes makes a mm-to-in conversion ($1'' \approx 25mm$) and inserts it into my output.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using just `siunitx` (v3) and the underlying `expl3` support:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\NewDocumentCommand\length{O{}m}{%
  \begingroup
    \sisetup{#1}%
    \qty{#2}{\milli\metre}%
    \ensuremath{/}%
    \qty[
      expression = ##1/2.54,
      evaluate-expression,
      round-mode = figures,
      round-precision = 3,
      quantity-product = 
      ]%
        {#2}{''}%
  \endgroup
}
\begin{document}
\length{100}, \length{101.6}, $\length{103.5}$
\end{document}
```

If you want to cover v2, you need slightly different set-up: a demo that works for both versions

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\ifx\qty\undefined
  \usepackage{xfp}
  \NewDocumentCommand\length{O{}m}{%
    \begingroup
      \sisetup{#1}%
      \SI{#2}{\milli\metre}%
      \ensuremath{/}%
      \edef\x{%
        \SI[
          number-unit-product = ,
          round-mode = figures,
          round-precision = 3,
        ]
          {\fpeval{#2/25.4}}{''}%
      }\x
    \endgroup
  }
\else
  \NewDocumentCommand\length{O{}m}{%
    \begingroup
      \sisetup{#1}%
      \qty{#2}{\milli\metre}%
      \ensuremath{/}%
      \qty[
        expression = ##1/25.4,
        evaluate-expression,
        round-mode = figures,
        round-precision = 3,
        quantity-product = 
        ]%
          {#2}{''}%
    \endgroup
  }
\fi
\begin{document}
\length{100}, \length{101.6}, $\length{103.5}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: A separate, genuine question: To denote feet and inches typographically, is one supposed to use text-mode or math-mode versions of `'` and `''`? (I thought one is supposed to show the text-mode versions, i.e., single and double text-mode apostrophes, but my impression may very well be wrong.)

Comment: @Mico I'd say it's the same symbol as minutes of a plane angle, so primes, but there are not really codified rules for the typography here: I think this is very much a personal choice.

Comment: @Mico Didn't I change that?

Answer (score 6):

If you're willing and able to compile your document with LuaLaTeX, the following solution may be of interest to you.

- If a millimeter-based length divides evenly into an integer-based inch-length, no decimal part is shown. You can control the number of decimal digits shown by modifying the string `"\%.3g"`.
- The macro `\length` is set up to permit a line break after the "slash" character that separates the two length terms. If you don't want to permit a line break, just change `\\slash` to `/`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx} % for '\qty' macro (formerly '\SI')
\usepackage{luacode} % for '\luaexec' macro

%% Lua-side code
\luaexec{
function length ( len_mm ) 
   len_in = string.format ( "\%.3g" , len_mm / 25.4 )
   tex.sprint ( "\\qty{"..len_mm.."}{\\milli\\meter}\\slash"..len_in.."\\mbox{''}" )
end 
}

%% LaTeX-side code
\newcommand\length[1]{\directlua{length(#1)}}

\begin{document}
\length{100}, \length{101.6}, $\length{103.5}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: I just tried to compile it in Overleaf and it gave me an error using `\qty` instead of `\SI` (which I read is the depracated version kept for backwards compatibilty). When I change `\qty` to `\SI`  your example compiles without a problem, is there any possibilty to have Overleaf accept this new version?

And I definitely have to learn Lua(LaTeX), as it seems to be very powerful and useful in many applications!

Comment: @Lukas - Until Overleaf gets around to providing access to version 3.0 of the `siunitx` package, you'll have to make do with `\\SI` instead of `\\qty`. (It didn't occur to me earlier to mention this factoid as I wasn't aware that you were using Overleaf, which is still based on TeXLive2020.) Indeed, because LuaTeX embeds Lua, LuaLaTeX can access Lua's powerful string library, including `string.format`. If you're familiar with C or one of its descendants: Lua's `string.format` function essentially implements C's versatile [printf](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) function.